# Не получается вставить объект в div

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Как добавить объект в DOM дерево? (не узел типа `div`), а именно объект (внутри которого уже прописано *css* у соответствующего `div'a`).

Пробую `appendChild`, но ничего не получается...

Вот код:

```
var little = document.getElementById('littleField'); //создаём див
    little.classList.add('little');

function Day(date, conteiner) { //конструктор объекта
  this.date = date;
  this.conteiner = conteiner;
}

Day.prototype.generateDate = function () {  //прототип объекта
  var day1 = document.createElement('day1');
  day1.classList.add('day');
  conteiner.appendChild(day1); //попытка аппендинга)))
}

var array = []; //обекты в массив и вставка в див.
while (i <= 29) {
  var i = 0;
  var obj = new Day(i, little); //создаём объект
  array[i] = obj;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Как обратится к свойству объекта созданного конструктором? conteiner.appendChild(day1); //попытка аппендинга)))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Работающая версия:

```
   var little = document.getElementById('littleField'); //создаём див
        little.classList.add('little');

    function Day(date, conteiner) { //конструктор объекта
      this.date = date;
      this.conteiner = conteiner;

    }

    Day.prototype.generateDate = function () {  //прототип объекта
      var day1 = document.createElement('div');
      day1.classList.add('day');
      this.conteiner.appendChild(day1); //попытка аппендинга)))
    }

    var array = []; //обекты в массив и вставка в див.
    var i = 0;
    while (i <= 29) {
      var obj = new Day(i, little); //создаём объект
      obj.generateDate()
      array[i] = obj;
      console.log(array[i]);
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: Вы руководителем никогда не работали? Просто Ваш ответ мне одного такого напомнил :)

Comment: да было дело :)

Comment: зачем минусовать то?

Comment: По личным и профессиональным соображениям. Если простыми словами, то Вы полную фигню написали.

Comment: Ну это ваш выбор, спасибо :) - а как вы бы написали ? просто интересно посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо! Очень благодарен за исправленный код, долго мучался!!

Comment: @Jackson я немного подправил код, проверьте

Comment: Можете не обольщаться, говорят, что если такие плюсики через сутки отменяются, так как считаются накруткой. Это к тому чтобы Вы не думали плюсами на минус ответили.  А автору я показал где ошибка ещё в комментах, могли бы подсмотреть.

Comment: проблема не была только в этом! чем писать комменты вам надо было просто просмотреть код.
внимательно просмотрите его еще раз!